# Is there a prequel series for Chicago P.D.?

Tags: chicago-pd

I have just started watching Chicago P.D. season one, the show has many references to the past especially about the characters history. The show's page on Wikipedia says nothing about it. What am I missing?

Comment: Characters often have [backstory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backstory).  What makes you think this relates to a prequel series?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Chicago * series, but am aware they are all in a shared universe. Is it possible some characters have been transferred over from other series and the references are to events in those other series?

Comment: WRT "The show's page on Wikipedia says nothing about it.": this isn't true. A quick glimpse at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_P.D._(TV_series) and I notice in the bio of the very first character listed in "Cast" the line "He is first introduced in Chicago Fire as ...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## NO

However, certain characters were *introduced* in other "Chicago" series, specifically, *Chicago Fire*.

Primarily these are:

> **Antonio Dawson**, portrayed by Jon Seda, is a fictional character in the Chicago franchise and is a main character in Chicago P.D. and Chicago Justice. He was introduced as a recurring character on Chicago Fire before the spin-off Chicago P.D. was created.
>
> **Detective Jay Halstead** previously appeared on Chicago Fire as an undercover cop assigned to take down a local mobster-cum-thug. He requests a transfer to the Intelligence Unit after the assignment ended with him getting shot but successfully arresting the mobster. Chicago P.D. begins a month following his transfer.
>
> **Hank Voight**, This character was first seen in Chicago Fire as an antagonist. Voight's ruthless methods cause friction with Lieutenant Matthew Casey, a firefighter at the nearby Firehouse 51
>
> **Erin Lindsay**, The character was first introduced in Chicago Fire, as one of the Chicago PD detectives the firefighters of 51 regularly come into contact with.

These characters and others have relationships with other characters that spread throught the various *Chicago* series such as *Chicago Fire* and *Chicago Med*.